# Nmap does not save WARNING messages in output file

Tags: nmap

I'm running a nmap command which seems it is impossible and needs some changes. In the console, it will give me a Warning but this message won't save in output file and I do not know why?

Here is a sample command:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nmap\\nmap.exe" -sL -sV -p 80 -T1 -A target.com -oA "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\output.txt"
```

> WARNING: OS Scan is unreliable without a port scan.  You need to use a
>   scan type along with it, such as -sS, -sT, -sF, etc instead of -sn
>   QUITTING!

Comment: Are they being printed to stderr? Try adding `2 > err.txt` on the end of that command.

Comment: You can also use the command line switch `--log-errors: Log errors/warnings to the normal-format output file`.

Comment: @douggard the err.txt will create but it is also empty.

Comment: @douggard --log-errors also did nothing :(